# find main row from nested table

Tags: html, jquery

I'm trying to select the previous main tr from a nested table using JQuery but have not a solution.

There are multiple rows with the same class name but I need only the previous one.

```
<table class="flttbl">

<tr><!-- I want to go here -->
  <td>hello world</td>
  <td class="eta">hello world</td>
  <td>hello world</td>
  <td>hello world</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <div>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>som text</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>som text</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>som text</td>
          <td onclick="goto(this)">some text</td><!-- I am here and I would like to go up to the previous tr outside the nested table -->
        </tr>
        
      </table>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I have this cose but is selecting all the '.eta' classes I just need to select the previous one

```
function goto(t){
var  eta = $('.flttbl').find('.eta')
$(eta).text(landing)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `closest` with `prev` for that task like:

```js
function goto(t) {
  var eta = $(t).closest('div').closest('tr').prev().find('.eta');
  $(eta).text('test')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="flttbl">

  <tr>
    <!-- I want to go here -->
    <td>hello world</td>
    <td class="eta">hello world</td>
    <td>hello world</td>
    <td>hello world</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>som text</td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>som text</td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>som text</td>
            <td onclick="goto(this)">some text</td>
            <!-- I am here and I would like to go up to the previous tr outside the nested table -->
          </tr>

        </table>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
```